# Checking set of values for combination

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I am using a group of enums to determine the value of 4 slots. There is one called none, and then 4 called fire,earth,water,air. The values of the slots are held in a dictionary of an integer as the index and the enum as the value. I want to check the values of this dictionary to see if certain combinations are present. I am not sure how to go about doing this most effectively without hard coding every situation. I know how I could store the combinations, but I am not exactly sure how to go about checking that against the values effectively.

The idea is if the combination is fire, fire, fire, fire, then it sets off a certain event/function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused about the dictionary because it sounds like you're just using the keys to indicate the sequence. I'm guessing this is a `SortedDictionary<int, Elements>` (although it may not matter.) But first:

To compare any two lists you can use `SequenceEquals`.

Let's say this is your enum:

```
enum Elements { None, Fire, Earth, Water, Air }
```

Let's say the combination you're checking for is:

```
var elementsToMatch = new Elements[] { Elements.Fire, Elements.Fire, Elements.Fire };
```

You could do this:

```
var matches = dictionary.Values.SequenceEquals(elementsToMatch);
```

It's true if both sets contain the same elements in the same sequence, otherwise false.

If the sequence isn't important, just the combination of elements, then you could sort them first:

```
var matches = dictionary.Values.OrderBy(v=>v)
    .SequenceEquals(elementsToMatch.OrderBy(e=>e));
```

Is a `Dictionary` necessary to do this?

You could do this:

```
var elements = new Dictionary<int, Elements>(); // or SortedDictionary
elements.Add(0, Elements.None);
elements.Add(1, Elements.Fire);
// etc.
```

Or you could do this:

```
var elements = new Elements[] { Elements.None, Elements.Water };
```

Or use a `List<Elements>`.

In any case the way you access it will be exactly the same:

```
elements[0]
elements[1] 
// etc
```

With a dictionary it's possible that a key could be missing. There might be an `elements[0]` and `elements[2]` but no `elements[1]`.

If the only reason for the Dictionary is to provide a position for each element then you could use an array or a list, because each element can already be referenced by its position.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me alot, and yeah i switched from dictionary like you said. At the time i had a idea in my mind, but i didnt comment it in  why i used a dictionary, so unless i find a reason to not use array/list instead , ill use them, t hank you again